# Which command in javascript click on the button nome = "form: j_id15"?

Tags: javascript, html, input, submit, onblur

Which function should I use in JavaScript to get the button with `name = "form: j_id15"`?

I already tried with `getElementId`, `getElementName`, but none of them worked. Does anyone have any idea how to do this?

The excerpt from the html page below:

```html
<input 
  type = "submit" 
  name = "form: j_id15" 
  value = "" 
  onblur = "return validarCPFCNPJ (this);" 
  class = "btn btn-blue"
>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's [`getElementsByName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByName). `"Elements"`, plural, as you can have more than one element with the same name. It returns a [NodeList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList), an array like collection of nodes. If you want to grab the first element with that name, you need to access the element at the zeroth index:

```js
const button = document.getElementsByName('form: j_id15')[0]

button.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
  console.log('submit button clicked')
})

// you can use the click() method
button.click()
// or
document.getElementsByName('form: j_id15')[0].click()
```

```html
<input type="submit" name="form: j_id15" value="Click me" class="btn btn-blue">
```

PS: If it's in a form, you should probably subscribe to the form's `submit` event, instead of button click.

Comment: The html code of the form already has the button, example of the code in the form:

<input  type = "submit"  name = "form: j_id15" value = "Confirm" onblur = "return validarCPFCNPJ (this);" class = "btn btn-blue">

I'm trying to run the javascript command line, on the Chrome console, to click automatically via the command, example:

document.getElementByName ("form: j_id15"). Click (); or . Submit;

But this command line does not work on the Chrome console

Comment: I've just updated my snippet, you can use `document.getElementsByName('form: j_id15')[0].click()`, it should work as expected.

Comment: It worked now ... thank you very much! May God bless you and your family

Comment: Great, thank you. If it solved your issue, you could also [accept the answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235) by clicking the check mark.